# Azure android build - SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building an Android app on my Windows server using Azure pipelines.
I already set up all the SDK settings and environment variables in the Windows server.
When I run the pipeline I get the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Agents\agent-x64-3.234.0\_work\17\s\local.properties'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Error: The process 'C:\Agents\agent-x64-3.234.0\_work\17\s\gradlew.bat' failed with exit code 1
    at ExecState._setResult (C:\Agents\agent-x64-3.234.0\_work\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.231.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:943:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (C:\Agents\agent-x64-3.234.0\_work\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.231.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:926:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Agents\agent-x64-3.234.0\_work\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.231.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:839:19)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:301:12)
```

Here is my YML file

```
# Android
trigger:
- master
- dev
- release/*

pool: 'Croem Build Servers'


steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    jdkDirectory: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin'
    jdkVersionOption: '11'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'clean build test assembleRelease assembleDebug'
```

I am attaching the environment variable settings as well.
[image]

My local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Umer\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: Not all processes do automatically catch updates to ENV variables. So may be the host PC just needs a reboot are at least a restart of the azure pipeline/devops  service?

Comment: Thanks, @Robert I rebooted the pipeline but it still has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, you have set the user environment variable(ANDROID_HOME) on your local machine.

You can also set the ANDROID_HOME in system environment variable.

For example:

[image]

You can navigate to **Organization Settings -> Agent Pool -> Select Agent -> Capabilities** and check if the ANDROID_HOME exists in the Capabilities list and has the correct value.

For example:

[image]

If it doesn't exist, you need to **Restart** your Self-hosted Agents. Then it will get the latest tool capabilities at startup.

On the other hand, if you use the local.properties,  the file local.properties needs to be inside the same directory as **gradle** stuff for gradle to find it when building.

Comment: Hi, I follow the same flow but still getting the same error.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Can you see the ANDROID_HOME in the Agent  Capabilities ?

Comment: yes ANDROID_HOME is in Capabilities.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Can you check your self-hosted agent mode? Run as service or interactive. The android should be install on your user account of the machine. You need to check if it is using your account to run the agent or you can install the android in the account which is used by agent

Comment: You can try to create an interactive self-hosted agent and run the agent with your account. And check if it can run the Gradle task.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin I put my Sdk in C drive instead of users folder resolved my issue.